# How to single number a set of aligned equations in two columns under the align environment?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, numbering, align

I'm having a difficulty in numbering only once a whole set of equations.  Currently, there are two numbers, each one for a single line.  I need to show only one number in the middle of the lines:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{nccmath,amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Blabla bla:
    \begin{align}
        x_1 &= \ell \sin \theta_1,
        &y_1 &= \ell \cos  \theta_1, \\
        x_2 &= \ell \sin \theta_1 + \ell \sin \theta_2,
        &y_2 &= \ell \cos \theta_1 + \ell \cos \theta_2.
    \end{align}

\end{document}
```

Usually, I would use the **equation** environment arount an **aligned** environment, but I need to reduce vertical space.  I can't figure out how to do this.  I could use `\nonumber \\ \\ \nonumber` instead of a single `\\`, but this is an hack!

Comment: You can use `split` but, from cat to cat, I find that horrendous. I'd use `\begin{subequations}\label{eq:whatever}\begin{align}...\end{align}\end{subequations}` instead.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat furry Schröd, it adds two sub-numbered numbers (with a and b), not a single number in the middle.

Comment: Yes, I know, but you can still refer to the full collection: `Blabla bla:
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:tensors}
    \begin{align}
        \tensor{x}{_1} &= \ell \sin \theta_1,
        &\tensor{y}{_1} &= \ell \cos  \theta_1, \\
        \tensor{x}{_2} &= \ell \sin \theta_1 + \ell \sin \theta_2,
        &\tensor{y}{_2} &= \ell \cos \theta_1 + \ell \cos \theta_2.
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}

As detailed in \eqref{eq:tensors},`

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, hmm.  You're right.  I may adopt this if there's no solution to get a single number for the whole set (without the letters a, b, c, ...).  In my main document, the letters may get confusing or useless.

Comment: The spacing is exactly the same for `align` and  a nested `aligned`.

Comment: @Bernard for me putting `equation` + `aligned` in a `\vbox` results in a smaller box than with `align`.

Comment: I just measured with my pdf viewer: if there's a difference, it is less than 0.1pt.

Comment: @Bernard, the **aligned** environment don't do columns like the **align** environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too many comments. You can use `split`, I have a strong personal preferences for `subequations`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{nccmath,amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}
%\newcommand{\tensor}[1]{\ensuremath{\boldsymbol{#1}}}
\begin{document}

Original \texttt{align*}
    \begin{align}
        x_1 &= \ell \sin \theta_1,
        &y_1 &= \ell \cos  \theta_1, \\
        x_2 &= \ell \sin \theta_1 + \ell \sin \theta_2,
        &y_2 &= \ell \cos \theta_1 + \ell \cos \theta_2.
    \end{align}

Naive \texttt{aligned}:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:aligned}
    \begin{aligned}
        x_1 &= \ell \sin \theta_1,
        &y_1 &= \ell \cos  \theta_1, \\
        x_2 &= \ell \sin \theta_1 + \ell \sin \theta_2,
        &y_2 &= \ell \cos \theta_1 + \ell \cos \theta_2.
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
We can refer here to the combined equations \eqref{eq:aligned}.

With \texttt{split}:
\begin{align}\label{eq:splittensors}
    \begin{split}
        \tensor{x}{_1} &= \ell \sin \theta_1,\\
        \tensor{x}{_2} &= \ell \sin \theta_1 + \ell \sin \theta_2,
    \end{split} 
    &
    \begin{split}
        \tensor{y}{_1} &= \ell \cos  \theta_1, \\
        \tensor{y}{_2} &= \ell \cos \theta_1 + \ell \cos \theta_2.
    \end{split}
\end{align}
We can refer here to the combined equations \eqref{eq:splittensors} as well.


With \texttt{subequations}:
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:tensors}
    \begin{align}
        \tensor{x}{_1} &= \ell \sin \theta_1,
        &\tensor{y}{_1} &= \ell \cos  \theta_1,\label{eq:tensor_1} \\
        \tensor{x}{_2} &= \ell \sin \theta_1 + \ell \sin \theta_2,
        &\tensor{y}{_2} &= \ell \cos \theta_1 + \ell \cos \theta_2.\label{eq:tensor_2}
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}
We can refer to the combined equations \eqref{eq:tensors}, \emph{and} to its
subequations, \eqref{eq:tensor_1} and \eqref{eq:tensor_2}.


One problem with \texttt{split} and \texttt{aligned} is that it can be ambiguous.
\begin{align}\label{eq:splittensors2}
    \begin{split}
        \tensor{x}{_1} &= \ell \sin \theta_1,\\
        \tensor{x}{_2} &= \ell \sin \theta_1 + \ell \sin \theta_2,\\
        \tensor{x}{_3} &= \ell \sin \theta_1 - \ell \sin \theta_2,
    \end{split} 
    &
    \begin{split}
        \tensor{y}{_1} &= \ell \cos  \theta_1, \\
        \tensor{y}{_2} &= \ell \cos \theta_1 + \ell \cos \theta_2,\\
        \tensor{y}{_3} &= \ell \cos \theta_1 - \ell \cos \theta_2.
    \end{split}
\end{align}
When one now refers to \eqref{eq:splittensors2}, it could either mean the
equations in the middle or all of them.

Some like to add a brace
\begin{equation}
\left.    \begin{aligned}
        \tensor{x}{_1} &= \ell \sin \theta_1,
        &\tensor{y}{_1} &= \ell \cos  \theta_1, \\
        \tensor{x}{_2} &= \ell \sin \theta_1 + \ell \sin \theta_2,
        &\tensor{y}{_2} &= \ell \cos \theta_1 + \ell \cos \theta_2,\\
        \tensor{x}{_3} &= \ell \sin \theta_1 - \ell \sin \theta_2,
        &\tensor{y}{_3} &= \ell \cos \theta_1 - \ell \cos \theta_2.
    \end{aligned}\quad\right\}
\end{equation}

With \texttt{subequations} there is no ambiguity:
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:moretensors}
    \begin{align}
        \tensor{x}{_1} &= \ell \sin \theta_1,
        &\tensor{y}{_1} &= \ell \cos  \theta_1, \\
        \tensor{x}{_2} &= \ell \sin \theta_1 + \ell \sin \theta_2,
        &\tensor{y}{_2} &= \ell \cos \theta_1 + \ell \cos \theta_2,\\
        \tensor{x}{_3} &= \ell \sin \theta_1 - \ell \sin \theta_2,
        &\tensor{y}{_3} &= \ell \cos \theta_1 - \ell \cos \theta_2.
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}
We can refer to the combined equations \eqref{eq:moretensors} without ambiguity.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Cham OK, I changed the answer accordingly. I also explain a bit more why I have a strong preference for subequations.

Comment: This answer is absolute perfection!  Meowww!

Comment: Purr purr purr!